# How to import a 10GB file to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

"I am trying to import a backup file to MySQL. The file is 10GB but the problem I get an error when the backup reach the limit of max_allowed_packet which is: 1GB. Any idea how can I increase this number to 10GB ?"

I've tried to use this command:

> mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql

But i get the same error

I expect that i have to change the max_allowed_packet and net_buffer_length  but how could i do that ?

Thank you!

Comment: set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 

set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the max_allowed_packet and net_buffer_length  through mysql command line client

```
set global net_buffer_length=10000000; 

set global max_allowed_packet=10000000000;
```